# Реализация Singleton

Tags: java, swing

Добрый день.

Есть вспомогательное окно, у которого реализован паттерн Singleton (с помощью статической ссылки на экзепляр класса).

```
public static SearchingResultsSwing getInstanceSearchingResultsSwing(Object[] searchResult) {
        if (instanceSearchingResultsSwing == null)
            instanceSearchingResultsSwing = new SearchingResultsSwing(searchResult);
        return instanceSearchingResultsSwing;
    }
```

Если окно закрывается с помощью штатного обработчика событий, в нем переменная обнуляется и все работает как надо.
Но если окно закрывается с помощью стандартного элемента Х, строка setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
то не понятно, как обнулить эту переменную?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете, синглтоны не должны обнуляться.

Comment: У вас не синглтон, а просто макаронный код.

Comment: Заработался...   Конечно, не статическая переменная, а статическая ссылка на  экземпляр класса                                    private static SearchingResultsSwing instanceSearchingResultsSwing;                                                                                        public static SearchingResultsSwing getInstanceSearchingResultsSwing(Object[] searchResult) {
        if (instanceSearchingResultsSwing == null)
            instanceSearchingResultsSwing = new SearchingResultsSwing(searchResult);
        return instanceSearchingResultsSwing;

Comment: @Tariel по поводу самого кода: обычно метод называют `getInstance()`. `SearchingResultsSwing.getInstanceSearchingResultsSwing` - это, скажем прямо, избыточная запись. И слово `Swing` в названии класса кажется подозрительным: не факт, что его стоило туда добавлять.

Comment: По поводу названия класса - на это есть объективные причины. Метод можно и переименовать.  А вот ответа на сам вопрос, к сожалению, нет

Comment: Да, метод стоит переименовать. А по поводу самого вопроса: что за переменная, которая обнуляется, - неизвестно. Что подразумевается "всё работает как надо" - неизвестно. Что за "штатный обработчик событий" - неизвестно (возможно, только мне, но всё же). Воспроизвести проблему без минимального нужного для этого кода не получится. Так как же в таком случае отвечать на вопрос?

Comment: ОК, перефразирую.  Как при вызове метода JFrame setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)  вызвать еще один метод?

Comment: Так вы же сами где-то в коде вызываете этот метод для установки операции, которая должна происходить при закрытии окна пользователем. Значит, в следующей строке кода вы можете вызвать ещё один метод. Сдаётся мне, что вы некорректно перефразировали.

Comment: Да не могу я вызвать в следующей строке. Мой метод должен вызываться только при вызове setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE), а не по порядку в коде.

Comment: Либо я вас не понимаю, либо вы не понимаете, что метод `setDefaultCloseOperation` только устанавливает режим обработки при нажатии на крестик. Обработчиком события закрытия окна этот метод никоим образом не является. Если вам нужно при закрытии окна какой-то код исполнять, то это делается совершенно другим кодом (обработчиком события закрытия окна): [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16296053/3432401).